# Empty label in widget Select

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

Here in Forms we can use the [empty_label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label). I use widget [Select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/widgets/#select), my choices are from database, does it possible to use here `empty_label`? In model I have:

```
position = forms.IntegerField(label=position_label, required=False, 
    widget=forms.Select(choices=Position.objects.all().values_list('id', 'position'),
    attrs={'class':'main', 'title': position_label},
    ), empty_label="(Empty)")
```

But the error is:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'empty_label'
```

How to set the label to 'Empty'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`empty_label` is a property of the field, not the widget. You already have a `label` set for `position`.

Comment: But I need empty_label 'Empty', not first 'position' from db

Comment: Then you need to revise your question. Your question was how can I fix the TypeError, not how to set the label to 'Empty'

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry for my inattantion. And does it possible [to set the label to 'Empty']? How do this?

Comment: Since you're returning a values_list, you can simply insert the value you need at the beginning of the list. Assuming `foo` is a list: foo.insert(0, ('Empty', '',)). More information on lists: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: `AttributeError: 'ValuesListQuerySet' object has no attribute 'insert'` I use `foo = Position.objects.all().values_list('id', 'position')`

Comment: Convert the result of the ORM call to a list first, then you can use `insert`

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to implement empty_label:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_name'].empty_label = "(Select here)"
        self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'main'
        self.fields['field_name'].queryset = Position.objects.all().values_list('id', 'position')

//OR   

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Position.objects.all().values_list('id', 'position'), 
        empty_label="(Select here)"
        )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Comment: Thanks for .widget.attrs['class']. I thought the shortest method was: .widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': '...'})

Answer (score 0):

from the Django Documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectDateWidget

If the **DateField** is not required, **SelectDateWidget** will have an empty choice at the top of the list (which is --- by default). You can change the text of this label with the **empty_label** **attribute**. **empty_label** can be a string, list, or tuple. When a string is used, all select boxes will each have an empty choice with this label. If **empty_label** is a list or tuple of 3 string elements, the select boxes will have their own custom label. The labels should be in this order ('year_label', 'month_label', 'day_label').